# Word level sentence generation using keras

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, keras, lstm

I am new to keras. I am trying to build word level sentence generation module using keras.
I use a vocabulary size of 8000 and one-hot-vector representation of words in my corpus.

This is my model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=False, unroll=True, stateful=False,input_shape=(1,len(itw))  ))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dense(len(itw)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer=optimizer,metrics=["accuracy"])
a,b =batch1()
model.fit(a,b,batch_size=45,nb_epoch=5,verbose=1)
```

here input dimension is 3 (as keras lstm expects 3d input)  input shape such that (batch_size,1,8000). I made the 2nd dimension as 1 because I want to feed word by word.
Batch_size is 45 because that is the avarage length of a sentence in the corpus.
All sentences are pretended with a "START_TOKEN" and appended with a "END_TOKEN".

len(itw) returns length of vocabulary which in my case is 8000

Now after training I wished to loop the generated words back as input until a stop token is encountered to generated a sentence.
But it seems that the model only considers the current input.

I hoped the model to consider the inputs before also and not just the current one.

So how should I change my model

Also is Keras unfit for nlp applications involving varying time serise

How to change the model such that it will generate the next word given n words.
Where n is any natural number